# Place the footer AND the copyright blocks at the bottom of the page responsive

Tags: theming

I installed Industrial Theme from Zymphonies and I am struggling to place the footer and the copyright (2 block layouts) at the bottom of the page.

[image]

So, on my website it looks like that.

I tried a lot of methods but I do not know how to deal with 2 containers simultaneously.

Comment: It's called [sticky footer](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/). Use the wrapper div that wraps both of those, if not add one.

Answer (score 2):

If you are indeed looking to create a sticky footer, not sure what option this particular theme gives you but the idea is the same with any drupal theme

- Add both blocks to a region that you will dedicate for this purpose
- if no available region exists you can just [create a new one](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-regions-to-a-theme)
- using custom css on your theme you can make this specific region `position: fixed` [but there are other ways](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) as mentioned by No Sssweat